# Choosing game model design

Tags: game-engine, godot

I need help designing a game where characters

have universal actions(sit, jump, etc.) or same across all characters; roughly 50 animations

unique attack patterns(different attacks) roughly 6 animations per character

item usage attacks(same across all characters) roughly 4 animations per item which could scale to 500+

What would be the best way to design this? I use blender for animations. And I just started a week ago.

I’m thinking of using either one model for everything and limiting actions or to create multiple and import those separately. Any help is appreciated!

Edit: also considering optimization since I don’t want lag to incur; making a mmo like game.

Comment: Do you want to make the animations once, and have them work with multiple meshes? I believe there is no animation retargeting solution in Godot core. If you want that, you might be interested in this project: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EJCHrdZrhOI - For the time being, I suggest to set the animations to the models in another tool before importing them to Godot, and remember to keep names consistent.

Comment: I found this add-on for blender that seems to be able to retarget animations: https://github.com/Mwni/blender-animation-retargeting - I also want to mention that there is a sister site for Blender questions: https://blender.stackexchange.com/ and one for Game Development: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This helps a lot. Thanks!

Comment: Yes I would like to have a library of actions that I can "paste" onto meshes ideally or remove them.

Answer (score 0):

There is an initial release (MIT License) of the module [GodotAnimationRetargeting](https://github.com/smix8/GodotAnimationRetargeting/branches) that I referenced in comments. **Update:** There is a GDScript version now.

Usually in Godot you have an animation player with the animations tied to a given model. Which means you would have to add them for all the models. However, this module allows you apply animations from an animation player to another model. You can also apply them partially (e.g. only rotation, or position or scaling of bones).

That should help you have a common set of animation applied to different models.

Being a module it requires to compile Godot using it. *See [Compiling](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/development/compiling/index.html) on the Godot docs.*